# Событие при выборе даты в datetimelocal

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть объект `<input type="datetime-local" name="startofvalidityperiod" class="form form-control form-control-lg" required="" id="id_startofvalidityperiod">`
Мне необходимо в скрипте JS сделать так, чтобы при выборе даты в данном объекте срабатывало события. Не могу найти событие, которое отвечает за выбор даты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {
    let date = document.getElementById('id_startofvalidityperiod');
    date.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
        console.log('date change');
    });
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" name="startofvalidityperiod" class="form form-control " required="" id="id_startofvalidityperiod">
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно и такое. (Воспользовался ответом от @Bamberg)

```js
window.onload = function() {
    let date = document.getElementById('id_startofvalidityperiod');
    date.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        console.log('date change');
    });
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" name="startofvalidityperiod" class="form form-control " required="" id="id_startofvalidityperiod">
```